# How to remove data frames from list with the same columns?

Tags: r, list, match, unique

I have a big list with over 100 data frames to work with. I want this list to only show unique data frames. The solution for that is quite simple: `unique(listname)`.

However, since it is quite messy data, sometimes the data frame is the same as others but a column is added. In this case `unique(listname)` will not work.

I am trying with a `for`-loop to fix the problem. But my solution seems very inefficient (and not working).

**Reproducible example**

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(151, 151, 151, 151, 151), name = c("Jan Slagter", "Jan Smit", "Monica Geuzen", "Marco Borsato", "Rafael van der Vaart"), status = c(5, 1, 2, 4, 5))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(152, 152, 152), name = c("Jan van Halst", "Herman van der Zandt", "Philip Freriks"), status = c(5, 5, 5))

df3 <- data.frame(id = c(151, 151, 151, 151, 151), name = c("Jan Slagter", "Jan Smit", "Monica Geuzen", "Marco Borsato", "Rafael van der Vaart"), status = c(5, 1, 2, 4, 5), control = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))

famous <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

In this case, `unique(famous)` will still return `famous`. In my case I want to delete `df3` out of the newly created `famous` list. My farthest attempt only returns an error when the first column (`id`) is matches any other `id` column in the list:

```
threshold <- min(sapply(famous, nrow))
for(i in 1:length(famous)){
  for(j in 1:length(famous)){
    if(i != j){
temp <- famous[[i]][[1]] %in% famous[[j]][[1]]
stopifnot(length(temp[temp == TRUE]) < threshold)
    }
  }
}
```

It is definitely not the cleanest solution and it is not at all what I want. But please note that I'd like a solution where I want to exclude the data frame in the list where *a whole column* matches any other data frame's same *whole column*. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink your search space a bit by first removing identical frames using `unique`, then for each data frame in your list only examine the other frames which include all of its column names and which have the same number of rows. Then you subset each of these frames by the column names of the index data frame and check whether the result is `identical`:

```
famous <- unique(famous)

remove_these <- unlist(lapply(famous, function(x)
  { 
    ss1 <- sapply(famous,      function(i) nrow(i) == nrow(x) & 
                                           all(names(x) %in% names(i)) &
                                           !identical(i, x))
    
    ss2 <- sapply(famous[ss1], function(i) identical(i[names(x)], x))
    
    if(length(ss2)) which(ss1)[ss2]
  }))

remove_these
#> [1] 3
```

So we can do

```
famous[-remove_these]
#> [[1]]
#>    id                 name status
#> 1 151          Jan Slagter      5
#> 2 151             Jan Smit      1
#> 3 151        Monica Geuzen      2
#> 4 151        Marco Borsato      4
#> 5 151 Rafael van der Vaart      5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    id                 name status
#> 1 152        Jan van Halst      5
#> 2 152 Herman van der Zandt      5
#> 3 152       Philip Freriks      5
```

This will always remove the wider of two data frames if they have one or more columns in common.

Comment: I'm reviewing your answer and trying to make the solution applicable to my data. The problem I have now is that in ```ss2 <- sapply(famous[ss1], function(i) identical(i[names(x)], x)```, you still compare whether two dataframes in the list are totally similar. The result from this line is ```FALSE```, even when one entry in ss1 is ```TRUE```. For me, it works to adapt the ```identical(i[names(x)], x)``` to ```identical(i[,1], x[,1])``` to myself identify the column I deem most important to identify whether the data is unique or not.

Comment: Okay. My solution is not a good one as it creates the problem that ```remove_these``` will have the value ```c(1, 3)``` and not ```3``` as in your example. Is it possible to do that based on one identifier column which we can use to see whether the data frames are similar (rather than the whole data frame)?